# WebBrowser control on AllowTranspPrent form is invisible

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, webbrowser-control

The webBrowser on Form with "allowTransparency = true" is hidden, it's well known issue, but has anybody a solution for this problem? For example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try with [Awesomuim](http://awesomium.codeplex.com/). It is a chromium-based web engine with a pure-WPF (no crappy activeX or COM stuff) UI.

Comment: I want just show one very simple html page, adding chrominium for doing this work is useless

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/changov/archive/2009/01/19/webbrowser-control-on-transparent-wpf-window.aspx
Hope it'll help you.